# Duo Security in Wordpress and IE9

Tags: css, security, wordpress, internet-explorer-9

I installed Duo Security's Two-Factor Authentication on a Wordpress site. I think it's a great service, and it's free for personal use.

It worked great, except on IE9, where Duo's prompts simply did not display when a user tried to log in and view the 2FA prompts. I reported this to Duo, and was informed that the issue was being worked on, but I needed a solution as the people using the site had some enterprise limitations and were all using IE9.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was surprised how simple the fix was. I realized that the iframe containing the security prompts was being pulled in successfully and not some browser-based restrictions on http and https mixing, but there was simply no visibility of the pertinent elements. I overrode style provided by Duo by changing the display of the iframe:

```
iframe#duo_iframe {
   display:block;
}
```

I haven't encountered any new compatibility issues by doing this. There are other ways to display the prompts using the native display:table, but the direct child elements at least need to displayed as table:cell.